# How to use Spring authorization in client side in GWT

Tags: java, spring, gwt, spring-security

I have been trying to implement role base authorization in the client side code to limit views for specific users.

I'm trying to use the following code to limit the view

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")    
public void create(Contact contact);
```

I'm also trying to add the following code

```
Authentication a = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();    
UserDetails currentUserDetails = (UserDetails) a.getPrincipal();
```

And then added the following in the module.gwt.xml file

```
<inherits name='org.springframework.security.core.Authentication' />
<inherits name='org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder' />
<inherits name='org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails' />
```

But it is giving following error while compiling

```
[ERROR] Unable to find 'org/springframework/security/core/Authentication.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
[java][ERROR] Line 22: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
```

Please suggest me where I'm going wrong and what can I do to make this work.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: *it's not possible*.

On the client side, only [a specific subset of Java is emulated](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/RefJreEmulation.html), and all the libraries you use have to be specifically made to work with GWT (including having their own .gwt.xml).

When you try to use the Spring classes on the client side, GWT will not know them and throw an error, and if you try to import the modules, it will look for the corresponding .gwt.xml file (which obviously doesn't exist because the Spring project was not made to work with GWT).

So, what can you do ?

- Protect all your RPC calls server side: event if the user can load the view, it will not be able to load the datas.
- Protect your .html page for non authenticated users (you have to create a different page for the login). This will prevent the access to the application to the users who are not logged. You can also have a look [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/articles/dynamic_host_page.html) for some other ideas including servlets/jsp.
- Make a RPC call every time a user request a view to check if he is authenticated/if he have the rights. It could be a good idea to cache this information client-side to avoid slowing down the application (don't forget to clean the cache when the user log-out).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Florent. I'll try what you suggested.